# How do I compute for the x and y coordinates of the end angle of a HTML Canvas arc?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an HTML5 canvas where I draw an arc of the circle using the code below:

```
c = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var startAngle = 0;
var endAngle = 0.25;
var xPos = 300;
var yPos = 200;
var radius = 100;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(xPos, yPos, radius, startAngle*Math.PI, endAngle*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

How do I compute for the x and y coordinates of the end angle generated by endAngle*Math.PI?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/8409844/2350085

Comment: Pi/4 is an angle (in radians).  It is equivalent to 45 degrees.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @nurdyguy no i think he means the end position of the path, where the arc ends in x/y position

Comment: Yes, that's what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If I understood you correctly,* you could achieve this in the following way ...

```js
var c = document.querySelector("#canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var startAngle = 0; //degree
var endAngle = 229; //degree
var xPos = 100;
var yPos = 100;
var radius = 60;

// compute x and y coordinates of the end angle relative to canvas
var x = xPos + Math.cos(endAngle * Math.PI / 180) * radius;
var y = yPos + Math.sin(endAngle * Math.PI / 180) * radius;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(xPos, yPos, radius, startAngle * Math.PI / 180, endAngle * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.stroke();

console.log('angle ended in position x:', x|0, ', y:', y|0);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I need! Thanks!